# Add existing cpp file to visual studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linker

I've tried: "source files > add > existing item" and selected the .cpp/.h files but I get still a linker error (possibly because my .cpp files didn't get passed into compiler):

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct Mem mem"
>   (?mem@@3UMem@@A)

How do I fix it?

Comment: Could be a hundred different things - check that it gets compiled first of all (For example add a `#error Give error here!` - which should make an error happen). If that doesn't make it obvious, then perhaps posting more details of what you are doing?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: It does. Give this message in both files I'm trying to add to project: `filename.cpp(8) :  fatal error C1189: #error :  Give error here!`

Comment: So, then it's clearly being compiled. Next check if it's actually in the link command - remove the `#error` line and add a line such as `extern int KerFlunk;` in a global scope - if you get an error that `KerFlunk` is missing, then linker is working, and you are simply missing the appropriate declaration - without showing us any code, we can only guess.

Comment: `extern int KerFlunk;` didn't give an error message. The number of error keeps same as previously: 2, about `unresolved external symbol`. What code should I show? I mean, I create a new project and tried to add two existing ones to current project but it did failed to compiler at linker-level.

Comment: Maybe you need to actually "use" `KerFlunk` (e.g. add `int x = KerFlunk` in some code) - I'm pretty sure the problem is in your actual code. Start by showing the declaration and definition of your `struct Mem mem;`

Comment: I found the solution. Check out my answer.

Comment: Well, that was kind of what I expected, but without source code, there are 50 other things that it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have `extern struct Foo` in header file which I forget to give an actual definition in some .cpp file.